# Excel vba Progress bar is not working: invalid property value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying the following code from excel vba tutorial but it fails: the ProgressBat is not updating, plus  `UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Value = UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Value + 1` line gets highlited with an error `Run-time error 380. Invalid property value".

```
Sub ShowProgressBar()
    Dim lAllCnt As Long
    Dim rc As Range

    lAllCnt = Selection.Count

    UserForm1.Show
    UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Min = 1
    UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Max = lAllCnt

    For Each rc In Selection

        UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Value = UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Value + 1

    Next

    Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

What may be wrong?

Comment: What element are you using for a ProgrerssBar?

Comment: @Vityata, Microsoft ProgressBar Control, version 6.0

Comment: Try the code that I posted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are exceeding the max value. Try this

```
For Each rc In Selection
    If UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Value < UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Max Then
        UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Value = UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Value + 1
    End If
Next
```

BTW I guess you forgot to mention `vbModeless` after `UserForm1.Show`

**Explanation**

When you set a minimum or maximum value of a progressbar then you cannot assign a value to it which doesn't fall in the range. For example, if the minimum value = 1 and maximum value = 5 then the moment you assign a value which is less than 1 and greater than 5, you will get an error.

This is the tested code

```
Sub ShowProgressBar()
    Dim lAllCnt As Long
    Dim rc As Range

    lAllCnt = Selection.Count

    With UserForm1
        .Show vbModeless

        With .ProgressBar1
            .Min = 1
            .Max = lAllCnt

            For Each rc In Selection
                If .Value < .Max Then
                    .Value = .Value + 1
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End With

    '~~> I have uncommented it so that you can see the
    '~~> Userform with the progress bar with it's values
    'Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not exceeding max value. I tried just to 'UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Value = 0 ' before the cycle and it gives the same mistake for that line

Comment: You cant set it to `0` as well because it is less than `UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Min` ;) The above code is tried and tested

Comment: How exactly should I use vbModeless?

Comment: Also, I changed min value to 0, so it shouldn't exceed max value in the cycle now, but it still gives mistake.

And above all, the progress  bar is simply not updating.

Comment: Thank you, it's all very clear now. The ProgressBar was driving me mad already!

Comment: BTW after `.Value = .Value + 1` you may want to add `DoEvents` to show the progress :)

Comment: What do you mean? The blue progress is showing just fine without `DoEvents`.

Comment: Doevents slows down the updating of the progress bar. And you can actually see it moving. You can also use `Application.Wait` like @Vityata used.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you should try to take a look at the min and max values. I have done it in a separate function. In general, it is probably a good idea to wait between the iterations, to see the progress bar updating.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ShowProgressBar()

    Dim lAllCnt         As Long
    Dim rc              As Range

    lAllCnt = Selection.Count

    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
    UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Min = 1
    UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Max = lAllCnt

    For Each rc In Selection
        UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Value = fnBigOrSmallIncrement(UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Value, 1, lAllCnt)
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
    Next

    Unload UserForm1

End Sub

Public Function fnBigOrSmallIncrement(lngCurrent As Long, lngMin As Long, lngMax As Long) As Long

    fnBigOrSmallIncrement = lngCurrent + 1

    If fnBigOrSmallIncrement < lngMin Then fnBigOrSmallIncrement = lngMin
    If fnBigOrSmallIncrement > lngMax Then fnBigOrSmallIncrement = lngMax

End Function
```

In general, if you are well familiar with Object Oriented Programming and you want to make your code better, try to rebuild the whole form as a class.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how Your progress form looks and what type of code You are using (maybe paste a link?) but when I used the progress bar I only changed the width property of the user form bar instead of its value, e. g. like here [http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/progress-indicator.html](http://here).

Comment: How does this answer the question?